# How do inner decorator functions see decorated-function arguments?

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator

I'm trying to conquer one of the final basic python features that I've avoided using since I started: decorators. I'm not grocking it like i did with list-comps, and I do not understand how an inner function within a decorator declaration works.

Here's an example of what I mean. Given this chunk-o-code:

```
def outer(func):
    def inner(*args, **kwargs):
        print('Hi my name is ')
        return func(*args, **kwargs)
    return inner

@outer
def decorated(name):
    print(name)


decorated('Bob')
```

I understand that this this will print

```
Hi my name is
Bob
```

but what I don't understand is how `inner` obtains any `*args` or `**kwargs` from `decorated()`

My understanding is that

```
@outer
def decorated(name):
    print(name)
decorated("Bob")
```

is equivalent to `outer(decorated("Bob"))`. If this is the case, how would `inner()` be able to access the `name` argument? Syntax issues aside, I'd expect the declaration for inner to look like `def inner(func.args, func.kwargs):`

What's going on here? What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Inner *itself* is defined as a function that takes `*args` and `**kwargs`, this is not something the decorator supplies.

Comment: so does part of the @ syntax involve passing the function arguments to `inner`?

Comment: `@outer` is called to replace `decorated`, so `decorated("Bob")` is `inner('bob')`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My understanding is that
>
> ```
> @outter
> def decorated(name):
>     print(name)
> decorated("Bob")
> ```
>
> is equivalent to `outter(decorated("Bob"))`.

That’s wrong. It’s equivalent to `outter(decorated)("Bob")`. `decorated` is replaced with the return value of `outer(decorated)` (which is `inner`). When you call `decorated`, you’re actually calling `inner`.

You can check that interactively:

```
>>> def outter(func):
...     def inner(*args, **kwargs):
...         print('Hi my name is ')
...         return func(*args, **kwargs)
...     return inner
...
>>> @outter
... def decorated(name):
...     print(name)
...
>>> decorated
<function outter.<locals>.inner at 0x7f5aec3461e0>
```

Comment: Thank you for interactive check tip. I explained decorators (and HOFs) many times but never used interactive python for that.

Comment: @AlexYu: best practice is to use [`@functool.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) to copy things like the name, docstring and other metadata and attributes over to the replacement wrapper function, in which case the `decorated` reference will have almost exactly the same `repr()` output, which is why you can't simply echo the decorated function object in real-life cases. A poor substitute is to echo `decorated.__code__`, which only includes the name `inner`, not the full `__qualname__`.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I'm aware about best practices. But when I explain something to somebody: at first goes explanation of inner work and only after that cames "best practices" and "why they are the best" and "are they really the best"

Comment: @AlexYu: that's good, but what I mean is that a lot of people encounter decorators in a framework or the standard library, at which point Jonas' illustration here will fall flat. It is one of the reasons you don't see much interactive demonstrations.

Comment: @MartijnPieters OK. You are absolutely correct when it cames to writing actual code. But before one will be able to write code - they must be teached how to do it. And that's where interactive explorations are great

Comment: Thank you! this clarifies the arguments bit I am still confused about the ```inner``` inheriting the actual functions? There are some examples I have see of decorators with arguments that don't explicitly specify the function that ```inner``` inherits?